# GWT Synchronous Script Loading

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, asynchronous

I'm looking for a way to ensure the ordering of external scripts in GWT. The way has to be compatible with SuperDevMode. The two ways I have come up with so far are

1. copy all javascript files into the war folder (undesireable); and
2. use ScriptInjector in onModuleLoad().

I have opted to go with option 2, however I wish to know if there is another way of executing scripts in a specific order besides cascading callbacks, as this results in a significant drop in performance. I was wondering if anyone else has run into this problem.

Below is a simple example of cascading callbacks.

```
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles() + "somescript.js").setCallback(new Callback<Void, Exception>() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Exception reason) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        // repeat ScriptInjector.fromUrl() n many times
    }
}).inject();
```

As of now I am looking for a way to asynchronously download all javascript files in parallel (to store in a String?), then use ScriptInjector.fromString(jsBody) to inject them in the order required. Is there a way of downloading the script bodies into a specific class using GWT? Any suggestions or improvements to my approach would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject scripts in your desired order by putting them into [TextResources](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#TextResource), which can be synchronous or asynchronous.

If you want to keep these scripts outside of your main app, you can load them first, then inject them in a desired order.

Comment: TextResource and ExternalTextResource only load files deemed safe (ie not javascript files). The solution I have found is similar to this which uses a similar implementation to ExternalTextResource with the safety validation removed.